# Alfresco Community Edition-5.1.x Analytics available?

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco Community Edition 5.1.x

I need to generate report for my Alfresco site and searching over internet I found [analytics](http://docs.alfresco.com/analytics/concepts/analytics-overview.html), but it is supported only for Alfresco Enterprise Edition not for  alfresco community edition.

Can any one suggest for some alternative Alfresco Community Edition analytics?

Answer (score 3):

You might try [Alfresco Audit Analysis and Reporting (A.A.A.R.)](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-audit-analysis-and-reporting-aaar) add-on.
It supports many versions of Alfresco both Community (from 4.0.x to 5.1.x) and Enterprise and can help you perform many analytics such as (reading from the site):

> NEWS: Starting from the v1.3 you can analyze the whole repository
> together with the audit data.
>
> Who is using the Alfresco E.C.M.?
>
> How the repository is growing up in the passing time?
>
> Which are the most viewed contents in the Alfresco E.C.M. last week?
>
> Who are the most active users in the Alfresco E.C.M. in the last quarter?
>
> Which is the created content during last week? And during last month?
>
> Which is the most accessed content of the last month? How many failed login?

You can also extract audit data and have it organized in various formats(pdf, xlsx, csv, etc.) and store them directly in Alfresco.